# How to navigate to a file inside a directory via Linux command prompt

Tags: linux

Please, I have been trying to navigate to a txt extension file inside a directory via Linux command prompt, but it shows "The directory name is invalid."

C:\Users\GACHIO\wamp\www\Project\etc\nail.txt

Comment: Thats a Windows path? just use `cd C:\Users\GACHIO\wamp\www\Project` to get to the folder.

Answer (score -1):

That's a windows Directory path. On a Linux OS the root of the file system will not start with "C:\".

Do you have the Windows file system (disk) mounted already within your Linux OS? If so you will need to use the Linux mount point as the start of your quest. I believe Ubuntu will automatically attempt to mount the HDD nowadays under the /media/"username"/"diskname" path

EX. (Ubuntu) to list the file
ls /media/bob/windows/Users/GACHIO/wamp/www/Project/etc/nail.txt

EX. to view the file contents
less /media/bob/windows/Users/GACHIO/wamp/www/Project/etc/nail.txt

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, I don't have the Windows file system mounted - I'm using Nodejs command prompt for my project.